# How can I use VNC to connect to Ubuntu 18.04 via a WiFi hotspot without Internet access?

Tags: networking, network-manager, vnc, hot-spot, ap-hotspot

I've enabled a WiFi hotspot and enabled sharing using the Gnome Desktop Settings and using bVNC on a phone, everything works as it should-- as long as the PC is connected to the internet via another port.  As soon as the internet connection is unplugged the VNC connection drops.

How do I get VNC to work without a connection to the Internet?

I've tried changing various settings using nmcli and gsettings org.gnome.Vino but haven't been able to figure out how to get the VNC server to listen directly to the Hotspot.

Comment: You can have it working (without internet) if both are in the same network. If not then internet access for both is needed, obviously.

Comment: The phone will connect to the hotspot on the PC and the PC can ping the phone.  The question is how to get the VNC server to listen directly to the hotspot. without a separate connection to the Internet.